# c++: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const int*&' from expression of type 'int*'

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, initialization

```
int *b = new int();
const int *&a = b;
```

The IDE showed "invalid initialization of reference of type `const int*&` from expression of type `int*`"

I don't understand.

Comment: The reason for this is [explained  here](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html) in terms of pointers. Consider the following: `const int i = 0;
int *p;
const int *&z = &p;
z = &i;` - `p` can't point to `i`. However, if this conversion is allowed, then you can change `p` through the reference to point to `i` and use that to change `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind references with different types; for this case they're `int *` and `const int*`.

For `const int *&a = b;`, `b` is a `int*` and then needs to be converted to `const int*` at first. The implicit conversion is allowed here, but the converted `const int*` is a temporary and can't be bound to `a`; because it's a lvalue-reference to non-const.

On the other hand, [temporary object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) could be bound to lvalue-reference to const or rvalue-reference, i.e.

```
const int * const &a = b; // fine, and the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference a
```

Note the position of `const`, now `a` is declared as an lvalue-reference to const pointer to const int.

Answer (score 2):

- `b` is a **pointer to int**.
- `a` is a reference to a **pointer to const int**.

So `b` is not assignable to `a`.

You probably want a reference to a **const pointer to int** instead:

```
int *b = new int();
int *const &a = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

The formal reason is that `int*` and `const int*` are different types, and the conversion creates a temporary, and you can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary.

Making it a reference to const pointer would work:

```
const int * const &a = b;
```

For a motivating example, let's assume that this were allowed:

```
int* p = nullptr;
const int*& rp = p;
```

`rp` and `p` now refer to the same object.

Let's make a `const int`.

```
const int y = 1;
```

Assigning `const int*` to `const int*` should be safe, right?.

```
rp = &y;
```

Now, since `*p` isn't const, we can assign a new value to it:

```
*p = 0xbaad1dea;
```

But `p` is the same object as `rp`, and `*rp` is `y` so `*p` is also `y`, and `y` is `const`

and now we're in the land of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these two types

```
int *
```

and

```
const int *
```

are two different types. Thus the expression in the right side that is the variable `b` is converted to `rvalue` of the type `const int *`.

You may not bind a non-constant reference to an `rvalue`. So you have to write

```
const int * const &a = b;
```